# Como criar atalhos com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

O Script que segue abaixo deveria permitir ao usuário digitar a combinação ALT+C onde abriria um prompt e a seguir o mesmo digitaria uma código para redirecionar para a página conforme o condigo numerico informado. O Script abre a janela de prompt do navegador e faz o redirecionamento correto mas em contrapartida bloqueia as demais teclas, assim o usuario não consegue digitar nada. Segue abaixo o código.

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
    console.log(e.which); // Retorna o número código da tecla
    console.log(e.altKey); // Se o alt foi Pressionado retorna true
    if ((e.altKey) && (e.which === 67)) {// Pesquisar (Alt + P)
     var comando = prompt('Entre com o Comando:');
     var codigo = parseInt(comando);
    }else{return false;}
/***************************************************************** */
/*Converte para Inteiro*/
if (!isNaN(codigo) === true) {

var url = "http://localhost/juridico/dashboard/";

  var meu_array = [
    /* MENU DE CADASTRO*/
    {"cod":201,"arquivo":"clientes"},
    {"cod":202,"arquivo":"fornecedores"},
    {"cod":203,"arquivo":"precos"},
    {"cod":204,"arquivo":"metas"},
    {"cod":205,"arquivo":"usuarios"},
    {"cod":206,"arquivo":"escritorio"},
    {"cod":207,"arquivo":"processos"},
    {"cod":208,"arquivo":"advogados"}
];

var indice = meu_array.indexOf(meu_array.filter(function(obj){
return obj.cod == codigo;
  })[0]);

  if(indice >= 0){
            var destino = meu_array[indice]["arquivo"];
            window.open(url+destino, '_self');

  }else{
    alert('Código Inválido! Tente Novamente precionando ALT+C');
    return false;
  }

}
/*SENÃO FOR NUMÉRICO*/
else{
    alert('Código Inválido! Tente Novamente precionando ALT+C');
    return false;
}
/***************************************************************************************/    
});
```

Comment: Não consegui perceber o problema. O atalho e consequente procura está a funcionar. Que parte especifica não está a funcionar ? [Veja o seu codigo a correr neste fiddle permitindo várias pesquisas seguidas com Alt+c](https://jsfiddle.net/jbz7z8jq/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema está no return false caso o usuário digite qualquer coisa que não o alt+c e no escopo do restante do seu tratamento.

```js
$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
  console.log(e.which); // Retorna o número código da tecla
  console.log(e.altKey); // Se o alt foi Pressionado retorna true
  if ((e.altKey) && (e.which === 67)) { // Pesquisar (Alt + P)
    
    var comando = prompt('Entre com o Comando:');
    var codigo = parseInt(comando);

    /***************************************************************** */
    /*Converte para Inteiro*/
    if (!isNaN(codigo) === true) {

      var url = "http://localhost/juridico/dashboard/";

      var meu_array = [
        /* MENU DE CADASTRO*/
        {
          "cod": 201,
          "arquivo": "clientes"
        },
        {
          "cod": 202,
          "arquivo": "fornecedores"
        },
        {
          "cod": 203,
          "arquivo": "precos"
        },
        {
          "cod": 204,
          "arquivo": "metas"
        },
        {
          "cod": 205,
          "arquivo": "usuarios"
        },
        {
          "cod": 206,
          "arquivo": "escritorio"
        },
        {
          "cod": 207,
          "arquivo": "processos"
        },
        {
          "cod": 208,
          "arquivo": "advogados"
        }
      ];

      var indice = meu_array.indexOf(meu_array.filter(function(obj) {
        return obj.cod == codigo;
      })[0]);

      if (indice >= 0) {
        var destino = meu_array[indice]["arquivo"];
        alert("Redirecionar para: " + url + destino);
        //window.open(url+destino, '_self');

      } else {
        alert('Código Inválido! Tente Novamente precionando ALT+C ');
        return false;
      }

    }
    /*SENÃO FOR NUMÉRICO*/
    else {
      alert('Código Inválido! Tente Novamente precionando ALT+C _');
      return false;
    }
    
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
```